# How to choose snprinf mask in template function for integral type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost

I have a template function that takes an argument of integral type and copies it to a character array on stack with `std::snprintf`:

```
static const size_t size = 256;
char buffer[size];

template <class T, std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>
bool to_array(T integer) {
  auto ret = std::snprint(buffer, size, "%lld", integer);
  return ret > 0;
}
```

The problem is that if this function is used with `int` type for example, compiler prints warning, that `"%lld"` mask reqiures `long long int` type.

To fix it, I used `boost::fusion::map`:

```
using bf = boost::fusion;
using integral_masks = bf::map<
  bf::pair<char, const char*>,
  bf::pair<short, const char*>,
  ....
  bf::pair<unsigned long long, const char*>
>;

integral_masks masks(
  bf::make_pair<char>("%c"),
  bf::make_pair<int>("%d"),
  ....
  bf::make_pair<unsigned long>("%lu")
  bf::make_pair<unsigned long long>("%llu")
);

auto ret = std::snprint(buffer, size, bf::at_key<T>(masks), integer);
```

This works, however it looks a bit heavy, and `boost::fusion` headers increase compile times dramatically. Maybe there is a better and easier way to do it?

Comment: why not just use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Well, it's a simplified example, I was tring to avoid memory allocation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're "trying to avoid allocation" and you're using boost anyways: use Boost Iostreams custom devices

> **PS** Lest it's not obvious, by using streams you get all the goodness:
>
> - combine with Boost Format if you want printf style or positional argument format strings
> - combine with Boost Locale for localized messages (`gettext`) and formatting (ordinals, dates, numerics, ...)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fff4691325aa7fa3)</kbd>**

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 128> buf;
    auto b = buf.begin(), e = buf.end();

    io::array_sink as(b, e);
    io::stream<io::array_sink> os(as);

    os << '1' << uint16_t(42) << uint32_t(42) << std::showbase << std::hex << int64_t(-1) << "\n" 
       << std::boolalpha << false << "\n"
       << std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

    std::cout << "result '" << std::string(b, os.tellp()) << "'\n";
}
```

This will just stop writing output after `buf` has been filled.

Realistically, you might just want the `back_inserter`. That way you get the best of both worlds: control over allocations while not restricting to an arbitray limit.

See also `std::string::reserve` for further optimizations. You can reuse the string as often as you wish without incurring more allocations.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef6e8ea2d16b9a73)</kbd>**

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
    std::string buf;
    io::stream<io::back_insert_device<std::string> > os(io::back_inserter(buf));

    os << '1' << uint16_t(42) << uint32_t(42) << std::showbase << std::hex << int64_t(-1) << "\n" 
       << std::boolalpha << false << "\n"
       << std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

    os.flush();

    std::cout << "result '" << buf << "'\n";
}
```

Both the above uses use Boost Iostreams in header-only mode (no runtime dependency on Boost (shared) libraries).

Comment: Thanks, I like the first code example. Unfortunatelly, I can't reuse a string object. Originally, I used `static thread_local string` in my code, but when I changed it to an array, benchmarks showed it become 3-6 times faster. So I think I'll use `array_sink`, it looks much better than `snprinf` and has no overhead due to my tests.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr const char* format_of(char) { return "%c"; }
constexpr const char* format_of(int) { return "%d"; }
constexpr const char* format_of(unsigned long) { return "%lu"; }
constexpr const char* format_of(unsigned long long) { return "%llu"; }
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/nVCDoT)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's a way to do it, but it looks a bit strange for me - first to create a generic function and than to specialize another function for every possible type to get a mask :) ... I thought maybe there is a more 'generic' way to do it?